# Needs some helps in graphic cars

Tags: ether

what's the super graphic card is a very suitable  for the mining  etheium and what is the exact CPU that suits it wuth RAM.

Comment: You can ask in reddit.com/r/EtherMining

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on multiple variables:

1. OS you are using;
2. amount of money you want to invest
3. amount of money you want to spend on electricity bills
4. may be some others

I'd suggest to start with this article - [ETH mining article](https://99bitcoins.com/guide-ethereum-mining-how-to-mine-ethereum/). It is long and will also answer questions, which haven't asked yet ;)